# How to run a loop and read URL in Angular 8?

Tags: json, angular, url

I have been trying to data from a URL to a JSON file and display it using HTML. The URL of the JSON has only 1 change ie only the last digit changes. It goes from 1 to 10, "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"

I have been trying to run a loop for the URL and read the data but I'm failing to do so.

Here is my app.component.ts file code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ApiService } from '../app/api.service';
import {User} from './user'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  title = 'JSON to Table Example';

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

  // let arrBirds: [number, number, string, boolean];
  arrBirds = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    var i;
    for (i=0;i<11;i++) {
      this.apiService.addUsers(i).subscribe(

        // data => {
        //  this.arrBirds = data.Object;     // FILL THE ARRAY WITH DATA.
        //  console.log(this.arrBirds[1]);

        data => {
          // this.arrBirds=Object.entries(data).map(([userID, ID]) => ({userID, ID, closed}));
          // this.arrBirds=Object.entries(data).map(([userID, ID]) => ({userID, ID, closed}));
          this.arrBirds.push(data);
          console.log(this.arrBirds);
        },(err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          console.log(err.message);
        }
      );
    }
  }
}
```

---

Here is my api.service.ts file code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    x ="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/";

    getUsers(): Observable<any> {
       return this.http.get<any>(this.x);
    }

    addUsers(y): Observable<any> {
      for(y=1;y<=10;y++){
        return this.http.get<any>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/y");
      }
    } 
}
```

When I execute this, only the first data in the URL gets printed 10 times.
JSON to Table Example!

```
userID  ID  Title               Completed
1       1   delectus aut autem  false
1       1   delectus aut autem  false
1       1   delectus aut autem  false
1       1   delectus aut autem  false
1       1   delectus aut autem  false
1       1   delectus aut autem  false
1       1   delectus aut autem  false
1       1   delectus aut autem  false
1       1   delectus aut autem  false
```

1   1   delectus aut autem  false
1   1   delectus aut autem  false

I want to read all the 10 data in the URL by running a loop for the last digit.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.
P.S I'm very new to Angular, 2 days in. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need another loop inside your service. Just change your `addUsers` function like this,

```
addUsers(y): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<any>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/"+y);
}
```

Comment: Im still getting the same output as earlier.

Comment: `console.log("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/"+y)` inside your addUsers function and make sure you are getting different URL.

Comment: @the_new_guy Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are passing `y` as a string rather than its value and

secondly, You are looping two times (in component and service) for same api call and in your service loop every time it will return for 1st iteration (i.e `y=1` and you will get same result for `id: 1`, ten times, so remove looping from service:

```
addUsers(y:number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/"+y);
}
```

> **[Working demo link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-frrkpn)**

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got the result that I was looking for.

Comment: you're welcome, if this solved your problem you can consider marking the answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

1. You are looping from 0 to 10 in both your component and in the service. You only need to loop once. Remove the loop from service.
2. The current code makes network calls one after another from the for loop. You can implement it better by firing all network calls in parallel using `forkJoin`.

   ```
     const networkCalls: Observable<any>[] = [];
     var i;
     for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
       networkCalls.push(this.apiService.addUsers(i));
     }
     forkJoin(networkCalls).subscribe(
       resultArray => {
         this.arrBirds = resultArray;
         console.log(this.arrBirds);
       },
       (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
         console.log(err.message);
       }
     );
   ```

   All network requests are stored as `Observable` in the `networkCalls` array and then fired at once using `forkJoin` on the array. This returns the response of all calls in a single array which can be directly assigned to `this.arrBirds`.
3. `addUsers` method is using `y` directly in the URL as a string. The value of `y` should be used instead. You also have the baseUrl for the API stored. So, you could construct the url using template literals. I have renamed `x` to `baseUrl` and `y` to `userId` for better understanding.

   ```
   baseUrl ="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/";

   addUsers(userId): Observable<any> {      
       return this.http.get<any>(`${this.baseUrl}${userId}`);      
   }
   ```

Working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-58444644) example.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got the result that I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just wanted to display 1-10 records from your API. So change your service as below - **api.service.ts**

```
  addUsers(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/");
  }
```

Now change your **app.component.ts** as below code.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ApiService } from '../app/api.service';
import {User} from './user'

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
 })

  export class AppComponent {
    title = 'JSON to Table Example';

    arrBirds: Array<any>;
    constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

      ngOnInit() {
       this.searchService.addUsers().subscribe(todo => this.arrBirds = todo);
     }
    }
```

Now you can display the records in your app.html file. I am gonna print 10 record's title fields only. In that way using table you can display all the fields of 10 records.

**app.component.html**

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let arrBird of arrBirds | slice:0:10">
     <h1> {{arrBird.title}}</h1>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got the result that I was looking for.

Comment: Nice to hear that :)